# Differential equation: chain rule

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chain-rule

I've the following system:
$$ r^2 \psi' = \frac{|L|}{m_p} $$
$$ (r')^2 + r^2(\psi')^2 - 2 \frac{G_m}{r} = 2 \frac{E}{m_p}$$

How can I find a differential equation for $r(\psi)$ using the chain rule $r'=\frac{\partial r}{\partial \psi} \psi'$ ?

Comment: what variable / parameters does $\psi$ depend upon?

Comment: What is the meaning of your symbol $\psi'=\frac{d\psi}{d?}$ and the meaning of your symbol $r'=\frac{dr}{d?}$ .

Comment: @JJacquelin The definitions are the same as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711643/movement-of-planets-keplers-law

Comment: @Kevin The definitions are the same as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711643/movement-of-planets-keplers-law

Comment: So, isn't it a duplicate of : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711643/movement-of-planets-keplers-law ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ r^2 \psi' = \frac{|L|}{m_p} \quad\to\quad \psi' =\frac{d\psi}{dt}=\frac{|L|}{m_pr^2}$$
$$ (r')^2 + r^2(\psi')^2 - 2 \frac{G_m}{r} = 2 \frac{E}{m_p}$$
$$ (r')^2 + \frac{L^2}{m_p^2r^2} - 2 \frac{G_m}{r} = 2 \frac{E}{m_p}$$
$$r'=\frac{dr}{dt}=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{L^2}{m_p^2r^2} + 2 \frac{G_m}{r} + 2 \frac{E}{m_p}}$$
$$\begin{cases}
dr=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{L^2}{m_p^2r^2} + 2 \frac{G_m}{r} + 2 \frac{E}{m_p}}\:dt \\
d\psi=\frac{|L|}{m_pr^2}dt
\end{cases}$$
A differential equation for $r(ψ)$ is : 
$$\frac{dr}{d\psi}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{-\frac{L^2}{m_p^2r^2} + 2 \frac{G_m}{r} + 2 \frac{E}{m_p}}}{\frac{|L|}{m_pr^2}}$$
The solution on the form of the inverse function defined by an integral is :
$$\psi(r)=\pm\frac{|L|}{m_p}\int \frac{ dr}{r^2\sqrt{-\frac{L^2}{m_p^2r^2} + 2 \frac{G_m}{r} + 2 \frac{E}{m_p}}}+\text{constant}.$$
You can solve it on closed form with change of variable $r=\frac{1}{\xi}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs! <3